# Getting empty string from QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This is the code I'm using:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/patcher/wait.txt?w=AACu6t8OAIyonlf6zpLX4VQquumCR5I5Tvukdg_e8gXGxg")));
```

This is my slot:

```
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    qDebug () << reply->readAll();
}
```

I get "" as output. Any reason why?

I'm trying to get text output from this [link](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/patcher/wait.txt?w=AACu6t8OAIyonlf6zpLX4VQquumCR5I5Tvukdg_e8gXGxg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an authenticated url. You have to provide auth credentials by handling `authenticationRequired` signal that is emitted by `QNetworkAccessmanager`. More [info here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#authenticationRequired).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by putting it in the public folder in DropBox and removing the s in https.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Also if you want to keep the communication encrypted via https, you can still use https; but you have to make a tweak to you code: QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/patcher/wait.txt?w=AACu6t8OAIyonlf6zpLX4VQquumCR5I5Tvukdg_e8gXGxg"))); reply->ignoreSslErrors();